# angularjs - initialize constant from template

Tags: angularjs, constants

I would like to 'dynamically' set constant based upon $location.

Alternatively I would consider reading a json file, using the .run()?  Is there an example somewhere?

I know I can prepend, $location.host() to in the controller.

I read one post that says you cannot use inject a $location since it is a service
Here is my code

```
var config_module = angular.module('myApp.config', []);

var config_data = {
    'GENERAL_CONFIG': {
        'APP_NAME': 'myApp',
        'EXPRESS_SERVER': $location.host() + ':3000'
    }
};

angular.forEach(config_data, function (key, value) {
    config_module.constant(value, key);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're outside angular at this point of your code, you can't use $locations, however, you can use native javascript object to get what you want, so your code would look like:

```
var config_data = {
    'GENERAL_CONFIG': {
        'APP_NAME': 'myApp',
        'EXPRESS_SERVER': window.location.hostname + ':3000'
    }
};
```